# No source available for FOO

Tags: c++

I encountered a new error/bug I have not seen before. What does this refer to or where should I take a look? Or what is the reason for such an error?

`No source available for "libstdc++-6!_ZNSsC1ERKSs() at 0x6fc89524"`

I suspect it popped up after this dummy data function:

```
template <class T>
void DummyDataStudents(Array <T> A){
    for(int i=0; i<A.lenght; i++){
        A.M[i].setStudent(i, i%2,"student"+i);
    }
    cout<<"Done Stundents"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I believe that this is your debugger telling you that it can't find the source code to show you where your program currently is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Nick already said, this message comes from the debugger which can't open the source file for the constructor of std::string (uce `c++filt` to decode this cryptic names).

Your problem is the `A.M[i].setStudent(i, i%2,"student"+i);` line, because you add i to the "student"-Pointer, making it "student" for i=0, "tudent" for i=1, "udent" for i=2, ... "" for i=7 and undefined behavior for i>=8. You can convert i into a string with `std::stringstream`.

Comment: Thank you, really apreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you for c++filt   I was trying to find out what  _ZNSsC1ERKSs meant!